# Perl script to encrypt file with GPG not working

Tags: windows, perl, encryption, gnupg, pgp

We currently have a job running on an old Windows server (Windows Server 2003) that needs to be moved to a new server, due to the old one being retired soon. This job runs as a Windows scheduled task, which runs at frequent intervals, calling a Perl script that encrypts some files using a vendor's public key and uploads the encrypted files to the vendor's external FTP site.

I am a self-taught programmer/developer/engineer who is not familiar with Perl, but I have been tasked with this move.

Here are the steps that I took to get this going:

1. Install Perl (Strawberry Perl using the Windows Binary exe from strawberryperl.com)
2. Install GPG using the exe from www.gnugp.com
3. Add the path to the GPG executable to the Windows Environment Variable "PATH", so that it can be run as "gpg" from the command prompt.
4. Add the vendor's public key to GPG using the command `gpg --import [path to the key file]`
5. Increase the trust for the imported key to prevent being challenged each time using the command:

   `gpg –-edit-key [name of Prudential’s key]
   trust
   5
   y`

I then took the existing script, made a few changes some of the constants used for file paths, etc., commented out the command that FTPs the files (since I'm just running an ad hoc test at this point) and attempted to run it to encrypt some sample files. The script ran successfully to completion, but, a friendly error message was generated due to the result of the command where the files are encrypted.

Here is the part of the script where the encryption takes place:

```
sub encrypt_outgoing_files {

    # open outgoing decrypted directory
    &message(sprintf("CD: %s\n", $out_dec_path), 0);
    if (opendir(OUT_DEC_DIR, $out_dec_path)) {

        # check for new files
        &message("Checking for new files\n", 0);
        my $file;
        my $new_flag;
        my %files_hash;
        foreach $file (readdir(OUT_DEC_DIR)) {
            if (-f $out_dec_path . $file) {
                $files_hash{$file} = (stat($out_dec_path . $file))[9];              
            }       
        }
        my @files = sort { $files_hash{$a} cmp $files_hash{$b} } keys %files_hash; # sort by mtime
        foreach $file (@files) {
            if (-f $out_dec_path . $file) {
                $new_flag = 1;                                              

                # rename and encrypt this file
                my $out_file = $file;
                $out_file =~ s/\.?[0-9]+$//i; # rename outbound files according to this regex
                &message(sprintf("Encrypting: %s (%s)\n", $file, $out_file), 1);                
                if (!system(sprintf("%s -e \"print('%s')\" | %s --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --output %s --local-user %s --recipient %s --sign --encrypt --cipher-algo %s %s >NUL 2>&1", $perl_path, $pgp_passphrase, $pgp_exe_path, $out_enc_path . $out_file . $pgp_extension, $pgp_sender, $pgp_recipient, $pgp_cipher, $out_dec_path . $file))) {

                    # archive decrypted original
                    &message("Archiving decrypted version\n", 0);
                    rename($out_dec_path . $file, $out_dec_path . $archive_dir . $file);
                }

                # error encrypting this file
                else {
                    unlink($out_enc_path . $out_file . $pgp_extension); # delete partially encrypted file (just in case)
                    &message("Error encrypting file (will try again next time around)\n", 1);
                }
            }
        }

        # nothing new
        if (!defined($new_flag)) {
            &message("None found\n", 0);
        }

        # close directory
        closedir(OUT_DEC_DIR);

        # clean archive
        &message(sprintf("CD: %s\n", $out_dec_path . $archive_dir), 0);
        &clean_dir($out_dec_path . $archive_dir, $max_archive_age);
    }

    # invalid directory
    else {
        &message(sprintf("Directory not found: %s\n", $out_dec_path), 2);
    }
}
```

For every file, I am getting the "Error encrypting file (will try again next time around)" message.

However, if I attempt to encrypt one of the files with GPG alone using the Command Prompt, the file is successfully encrypted.

So, I have three questions:

1. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the error?
2. How can I find out the reason for the error?
3. Is there a "better" way to accomplish this task, as this script was originally written over a decade ago? The script will now be running on a Windows 2012 virtual machine with IIS, Java, and ColdFusion running on it.

Comment: Can you redirect `stderr` and `stdout` to some file (like `>stdout.log 2>stderr.log` and check them afterwards?

Comment: Also, I'd print up the result of `sprintf` to be sure the line looks the way it should be.

Comment: @raina77ow when I add the `stdout` and `stderr` redirects, the `stderr` file is empty and the `stdout` displays what I normally see in the Command Prompe ("Error encrypting file....").

Comment: My suggestion was about redirecting them in `sprintf` output, not at the way you call your script.

Comment: @raina77ow I used a local variable to store the result of the `system()` call and print it, and it is "512". Any idea what that means?

Comment: @raina77ow Ok, I finally understand about the error output and did what you said and here's the error: `gpg: skipped [local user]: No secret key
gpg: [filename]: sign+encrypt failed: No secret key`. I'm guessing I need to get this secret key from the old machine...

Comment: @raina77ow I figured it out. At first I only exported/imported the vendor's public key. I failed to export/import our private key and trust it correctly. It's now working. Wouldn't have been possible without your help. THANK YOU!

Answer (score -1):

one things I found out the hard way is whatever account you use to import your keys, you must also use for any other task related to keys.  try looking into that